# Finding string in a file name

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch file wherein I have read the filenames of all the files in a directory and then look for a particular string in the filenames. I am able to get the filenames but unable to find a way to search for a particular string in the filename.

e.g. Name of the file is abc_account_march_2010.csv. I have to check if the filename contains the word "account" in it or not if it does then rename the file.

this is what I have done to get the file name.

```
FOR /R %completepath% %%G IN (*.csv) DO (
  echo %%~nG
)
```

%completepath% - is the path to my directory/folder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the wildcard that includes `account`.

```
FOR /R %completepath% %%G IN (*account*.csv) DO (
  echo %%~nG
)
```

If you still need to process all *.csv files and additionally rename those, that have 'account' in their names, then here's how you could check that:

```
FOR /R %completepath% %%G IN (*.csv) DO call :process "%%~nG"
GOTO :EOF

:process
SET %name%=%~1
SET chkname=%name:*account=?%
IF "%chkname:~0,1%"=="?" (
  ECHO %name% -- this is account file!
) ELSE (
  ECHO %name% -- this is NOT account file
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [grep](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ugrep.htm) can help you?

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims= " %%m IN (`findstr /c:"-stringtolookfor" "*.csv"`) DO 
(
   set first_word_in_this_line=%%m
)
```