# dir command to list file names ending with " d.jpg"

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Can dir command be used to list files whose name ends with `" d.jpg"`? Please note the leading space.

I need to differentiate two kinds of file names, one ending with `" d.jpg"` (a space followed by `d.jpg`), the other `"xxd.jpg"` (alphabets followed by `d.jpg`, no space). Well, actually, there is a space BEFORE the alphabets but not before the d.) For example, `D953 D.JPG` and `D953 SHD.JPG`.

I can list the latter using `dir *shd.jpg` or `dir *d.jpg`. How do I list the former without listing the latter?

I have tried `dir *" d".jpg`, `*" "d.jpg`, `*" d.jpg"`, `*?d.jpg`. None worked.

Comment: What type of list do you want? Do you want the normal `dir` list, or just a list of filenames or what? Please differentiate between "former" and "latter" since you switch the order of your examples - `"D953 D.JPG" and "D953 SHD.JPG"` and `"dir *shd.jpg" or "dir *d.jpg"`

Comment: Here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990892/finding-string-in-a-file-name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990892/finding-string-in-a-file-name) is it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes must surround the names. What do you think quotes inside the string do?

```dos
dir "* d.jpg"
dir "* shd.jpg"
```

Answer (score -2):

use:

```
dir *d.jpg
```

if you wanna look in sub folders use

```
dir /s *d.jpg
```

good luck.

Comment: That's simply wrong, you need quotation marks to preserve the _space_!