# How to show files from specific file type in CMD?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have just written some "code" in Batch to show how many songs are in my library.
So far, what I have is this:

```
F:
cd Music
set /A music=0
for /F %%i in ('dir /B /A-d') do set /A music=music+1
echo There are %music% Audio-Files in your library.
```

The problem is that this code counts all of the files, even if there's a JPEG or something else in it.
But now I want to specify the output by filetypes. How can I get this code to output something like:

**"There are (number) Audio-Files in your library. (number) files are in mp3, (number) files are in WAV"**

and so on.

Is this possible with this type of commands or do I have to re-write all of this?
I hope you understand what I mean.

Many Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dir command to list file names ending with " d.jpg"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41355905/dir-command-to-list-file-names-ending-with-d-jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dir supports wildcards (* - replaces this with every string) and you can put more than one filter for them:

```
F:
cd Music
set /A music=0
for /F %%i in ('dir /B /A-d *mp3 *flac') do set /A music=music+1
echo There are %music% Audio-Files in your library.
```

Comment: It should read `*.mp3 *.flac` (mind the `.`), right?

Comment: I haven't tried it with `.` yet because without the dot (`*flac *mp3` and so on) it just works perfectly fine! :)